# How to collate multiple csv files into one csv file, removing the headers each time?

Tags: python, csv, pip, urllib

I have downloaded about 100 csv files from the web using python. Each file is is for a month in a year, so effectively I am downloading time series data.

Now what I want is to put all of these csv files into one csv file in time order, i'm not sure how to do this one after eachother?

Also I should note that excluding the first time, I want to remove the headers every time I put a new csv file in.

This will make sense why when you see my data:

[image: csv file one]

Appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Are the contents of each CSV files already time-ordered?

Comment: Yes, like you see above, they start on 1/01/2016 0:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort your CSV files by time (presumably this can be done with an alphanumeric sort of the filenames) and then just concatenate all of them together. This is probably easier to do in bash than in python but here's a python solution (untested):

```
from glob import glob
# Fetch a sorted list of all .csv files
files = sorted(glob('*.csv'))

# Open output file for writing
with open('cat.csv', 'w') as fi_out:
    # iterate over all csv files
    for i, fname_in in enumerate(files):
        # open each csv file
        with open(fname_in, 'r') as fi_in:
            # iterate through all files in the csv file
            for i_line, line in enumerate(fi_in):
                # Write all lines of the first file (i == 0)
                # For all other files write all lines except the first one (i_line > 0)
                if i_line > 0 or i == 0:
                    fi_out.write(line)
```